# API is successful with request but fails with axios

Tags: node.js, ajax, axios

I was doing auth0's code grant flow with pkce and there was an api call for fetching tokens in auth0 docs like this -

```
var request = require("request");

var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN/oauth/token',
  headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  form: {
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    code_verifier: 'YOUR_GENERATED_CODE_VERIFIER',
    code: 'YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CODE',
    redirect_uri: 'https://YOUR_APP/callback'
  }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

Now this successfully works and gets tokens, but if I try to do same request with axios it fails and returns 401 unautorized error. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? My guess is that I am not sending the body correctly.

```
const axios = require("axios");

async function getTokens() {
const body =  {
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    code_verifier: 'YOUR_GENERATED_CODE_VERIFIER',
    code: 'YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CODE',
    redirect_uri: 'https://YOUR_APP/callback'
  };

const headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};

const data = axios.post("https://YOUR_DOMAIN/oauth/token", body, {headers});

console.log(data);

}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi! Have you tried adding the withCredentials flag, set to true, to the request? And can you check the request headers in chrome dev tools for instance, to see if there is a difference between the requests?

Comment: @brance Yes, it didn't work with withCredentials flag set to true. Also, I am calling this api at backend so I can't check with chrome dev tools.

Comment: Could you try to use .then((response) => {console.log(response)}, (error) => {console.log(error)}) on the axios.post call, and removing the 'const data =' part, to see if there are any additional infos in the error message.

Comment: @brance tried that too. Removed async await and tried the good old callback method but still . What i really think the problem is the way i am sending the body.